# redis failed jobs not saving in failed_jobs table

Tags: laravel, redis

I am using Redis as queue connection and jobs are processing with redis fine , But failed jobs are not saving in failed_jobs table and when I run php artisan queue:retry all its says no retry able jobs, but I can see failed jobs in telescope.

I am using laravel 10

Here are configurations

check Redis configuration, Tried php artisan queue:failed, and redis cli also php artian queue:retry

Comment: are you sure the jobs were not automatically retried and were successful on the subsequent tries? As far as I know, a failed job is removed from the failed_jobs table if it is successful on the automatic retry.

Comment: Failed jobs are now saving in table , i figured out and resolved the issue, but i am still curious is there any way to push failed jobs from redis in to queue those are not in failed jobs table

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not modified the default values in "Failed Queue Jobs" section of the config/queue.php file, and you have not mistakenly set those values through your .env file.

Comment: There was a problem with failed_jobs table default migration from 2019, I re migrated 2023  failed jobs table migration and its worked for me.